# Parentheses around year, "normal number" in footnote and a word before footnote

Tags: biblatex

I've got three problems with my document's `\footcite` for which I can't find a solution. My MWE is the following:

```
\documentclass[%
draft=false,%
paper=a4,% 
fontsize=12pt,%
]{scrbook}

\usepackage[%
 backend=biber,%
 style=authoryear,%
 bibstyle=authoryear,%
 citestyle=authoryear,%
 sorting=anyt,%
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Hong.2018,
 author = {Hong, KiHoon and Park, Kyounghoon and Yu, Jongmin},
 year = {2018},
 title = {Crowding Out in a Dual Currency Regime? Digital Versus Fiat 
Currency},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
Sentence~\footcite[S.~4]{Hong.2018}
\end{document}
```

Now I want the following three things to change in the footnote:

1. Put parentheses around the year (just the year) not the pagenumber
2. Write "Vgl." before the footnote begins (after the number of the footnote)
3. Write the number of the footnote as "normal number" not as an exponent.

The current output:

> ¹Hong, Park, and Yu 2018, S. 4.

should look like this:

> 1 Vgl. Hong, Park, and Yu (2018), S. 4.

What is the easiest / best way to make this happen?

Comment: `sorting=anyt,` makes little sense with `style=authoryear,` since `anyt` sorts by the alphabetic label associated with `style=alphabetic`. I suggest you drop `sorting=anyt,` (which will give you the default sorting `nyt`). `style=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is equivalent to `style=authoryear`. Finally you should not have to write `\footcite[S.~4]{Hong.2018}`, `\footcite[4]{Hong.2018}` is enough, `biblatex` adds the page prefix for you automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Point 1 is fairly simple if you use `biblatex-ext`'s drop-in replacement for `authoryear`, `ext-authoryear`. Then you only need

```
\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}
```

Point 2 can be achieved with the optional pre-note argument

```
Lorem\autocite[Vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}
```

Point 3 can be achieved with

```
\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\enskip}
```

In total and keeping in mind my comments under the question (1) that `sorting=anyt` is not really appropriate for `authoryear`-like styles since it bases its sorting on the alphabetic label of the `style=alphabetic` that is not present in `authoryear`-like styles, (2) that `style=authoryear, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear,` is the same as `style=authoryear` and (3) that there is no need to specify "S.~" manually since `biblatex` adds it automatically if appropriate, we get

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,ngerman]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
 backend=biber,
 style=ext-authoryear,
 autocite=footnote,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareInnerCiteDelims{footcite}{\bibopenparen}{\bibcloseparen}

\deffootnote{1.5em}{1em}{\thefootnotemark\enskip}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite[Vgl.][380]{sigfridsson}
\end{document}
```

[image: 1 Vgl. Sigfridsson und Ryde (1998), S. 380.]

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your detailed answer. This works for me.

Just out of curiosity - is there a central way to archive Point 2 so that i don't have to type it before every cite?

Comment: @Christian It is possible, but what if you don't want "vgl." because you have a word-for-word citation?